# What is the difference between log4j RollingFileAppender vs DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j

What is the difference between log4j `RollingFileAppender` vs `DailyRollingFileAppender`?
And why would I use one versus the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reading http://www.mail-archive.com/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/msg08183.html

> - DailyRollingFileAppender - Rotates based on dateFormat
> - RollingFileAppender - Rotates based on a maximum file size.

Also check:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

Answer (score 7):

On `DailyRollingFileAppender` the file is rolled over at a **user chosen frequency**, but on `RollingFileAppender` the file is rolled when the file reaches certain **size**.

Comment: Not necessarily, because you can create daily rolling appender using RollingFileAppender and it's rollingPolicy attribute, where you define how often to roll. See the [log4j extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) which provides lots of bugfixes to the 1.2 line and a few improvements.

Comment: Hi soltysh ! Can you please mention how we can proceed that kind of configuration. I have post a similar kind of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056481/log4j-configure-rollingfileappender-for-backup-log-files-as-dailyrollingfileap . Thanks.

Comment: @pconcepcion How can one test daily rolling file appender in local system? Can't wait till midnight to check if rollover occurs or not?

Comment: @gaurav I have not tested this, but I think you can either change the device hour, or maybe test with a different / shorter frecuency that will be probably more useful for testing.