# Trigger Log4j rollover (RollingFileAppender) for testing purposes

Tags: logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

I switched from the old (and unsafe) [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) to the new [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html). So now I wanted to test my configuration however I can't seem to trigger the rollover mechanism. Which time does log4j check to decide to roll over the log? I tried to set the system time back/to the future, changed the times in the log, change the file time...No luck!
Or is my configuration wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

     <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="some.log" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="%d.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%-5p] %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

...<!--appreviated for clarity-->

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Reading http://www.mail-archive.com/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/msg08183.html

```
    DailyRollingFileAppender - Rotates based on dateFormat
    RollingFileAppender - Rotates based on a maximum file size.
```

Also check:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

From:

[What is the difference between log4j RollingFileAppender vs DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884705/what-is-the-difference-between-log4j-rollingfileappender-vs-dailyrollingfileappe)

Comment: I followed the description [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html) stating that: %d - Daily rollover (at midnight). Due to the omission of the optional time and date pattern for the %d token specifier, the default pattern of "yyyy-MM-dd" is assumed, which corresponds to daily rollover.

Comment: Maybe this will help you so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884705/what-is-the-difference-between-log4j-rollingfileappender-vs-dailyrollingfileappe

Comment: @Destrif How can one test daily rolling file appender in local system? Can't wait till midnight to check if rollover occurs or not?